# Ubuntu and VLC - make default and hue

Tags: video, video-player

I have recently installed VLC. I have found that when I play videos on VLC, the hue of the color of the video is off. I have to constantly readjust it.

Also how can I make VLC my default player for `*.avi` files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the hue and make it "stick":
1. go to "Tools->Preferences"
2. click "Show settings->All" (lower left corner)
3. expand "Video" & click on "Filters"
4. enable "Image properties filter" under "Video filter module"
5. expand "Filters" & click on "Image adjust"
6. set hue to your preference and press "Save"
7. restart vlc
8. ??!...
9. profit!

boy, i never thought i'd need to figure this one out.

To set VLC as default player for AVIs:
1. On an avi file right click and go to "Properties" then to the "Open With" tab
2. select "VLC media player"
3. ...more profit!

Comment: No no no - it should go like this: 7. Restart VLC  8. ???  9. Profit! [Link](http://www.fool.com/news/foth/2001/foth011108.htm)

Comment: corrected. thanks! I hadn't known about the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Find an avi file [right click] > Properties > click Open With tab and then select VLC.  This should make vlc open all avi files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the problem with the Hue. But to make VLC your default player for `*.avi` files you can just [right-click] one > Properties > Open with tab and select VLC as the default player.