# Why do my AVI files display with funky colors?

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu and vlc — make default and hue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906/ubuntu-and-vlc-make-default-and-hue)

When I capture HD video with a Pentax DSLR, and view it using VLC, it looks wrong - the green grass is purple, and the golden retriever is blue.

This happens with VLC, Totem, etc.  There's nothing wrong with the files themselves - the exact same files play fine on the mac or the PC.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/906/270) question. Since you are using vlc, did you try the steps mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906/ubuntu-and-vlc-make-default-and-hue/913#913) ?

Comment: That didn't solve the problem, unfortunately.  Image would not display at all when I change the hue according to those steps.