# Weird color problem with movie players

Tags: 10.10, gnome, graphics, vlc

Both the built-in Gnome movie player and vlc both have strange color distortions : human skin color changes to blue; if it was pink it changes to green ; if it was yellow it changes to pink.
The weird part is that when I watch clips in the browser the colors are right.
Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ubuntu and vlc -- make default and hue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/906/ubuntu-and-vlc-make-default-and-hue)

Comment: It's a hue issue. Don't know why it hasn't been fixed because the number of people with the problem suggests it's a bug somewhere.

Comment: anything i can do to fix that? maybe to reinstall the codecs or something along the line? and btw i don't think it has something to do specifically with vlc since it happens with the default gnome movie player .

Comment: i've only ever had this problem with ogv.  hopefully someone with the problem more consistently can pin it down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by running `gstreamer-properties` in the console and I changed the plug-in option under "video" from `autodetect` to  `x windows system` (no Xv).
It seems it was some kind of problem with totem.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention i have nvidia 9400 gt and i used their drivers and not the open source from what i read the open source drives don't have that problem.

Comment: thx 4 sharing your solution...i see way too many threads where the user solves their own issue and doesn't post what they did

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I had to reboot for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

[The first answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/12878/22949) didn't work for me so i fixed it using [this article](http://linuxhub.net/2010/06/fix-color-issues-in-videos-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/) in 2 minutes.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.